# This program is crashing, why?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,int> > arr;
    arr[0].first=20,arr[0].second=1;
    arr[1].first=3,arr[1].second=2;
    arr[2].first=230,arr[2].second=3;
    arr[3].first=230,arr[3].second=4;
    arr[4].first=202,arr[4].second=5;
    arr[5].first=-20,arr[5].second=6;
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it;
    for(it=arr.begin();it!=arr.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first<<it->second<<endl;
    }
}
```

This program isn't running properly, what can be possible reason behind this?
Also I want to have sorted pairs vector in which sorting is done by the value.

Comment: [`vector<pair<int,int> > arr(6);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) should fix the problem.

Comment: And one question per question please.

Comment: When you create a vector using the default constructor, the vector is ***empty***. Any indexing will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning to a `vector` doesn't allocate memory.
Usually we use `push_back` to add items with auto-memory 
allocation. Code like that you usually write like so:

```
arr.push_back(pair<int, int>(20, 1));
arr.push_back(pair<int, int>(3, 2));
```

etc..

But nowadays with C++11 this style of coding is old.
It's possible to do it like that (see also the loop):

```
arr.push_back({ 20, 1 });
arr.push_back({ 3, 2 });
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
for (auto p : arr)
{
    cout << p.first << p.second << endl;
}
```

Actually, C++11 puts some convenient syntax into the constructors:

```
vector<pair<int, int> > arr{ { 20, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 230, 3 },
{ 230, 4 }, { 202, 5 }, { -20, 6 } };
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
for (auto p : arr)
{
    cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: "vector<pair<int, int> >" - also in C++11, the space between the closing angle brackets is no longer necessary. However, `template <boo> struct d; d<(1>2)> x;`...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `map::operator[]`, `vector::operator[]` never auto-inserts a new element into the container. It is undefined behavior to access non-existing elements (in debug mode the runtime may throw an assertion to aid debugging).

In C++11 the most efficient ways to populate a vector are:

Via an initializer-list:

```
  vector<pair<int, int>> arr {
    {  20, 1 }, {   3, 2 }, { 230, 3 },
    { 230, 4 }, { 202, 5 }, { -20, 6 } };
```

Or create entries in-place:

```
  vector<pair<int, int>> arr;
  arr.reserve(6); // optional, is just for efficiency
  arr.emplace_back( 20, 1);
  arr.emplace_back(  3, 2);
  arr.emplace_back(230, 3);
  arr.emplace_back(230, 4);
  arr.emplace_back(202, 5);
  arr.emplace_back(-20, 6);
```

Comment: Why isn't allocating memory through ctor also "the most efficient" way?

Comment: You mean `arr(6);`? That doesn't just allocate memory, it also default-constructs 6 elements. Granted, the `pair<int,int>` default constructor is a no-op, the approach is still more error-prone (risk of using an uninitialized value if not every element is subsequently set). And if the default constructor does happen to initialize the element then it would be wasteful.